# use globals variables in cibonfire codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using bonfire for my project.

I have to fetch `userid` from the database according to `username` and use that userid in every view.

Right now what I am doing is I have a model function and that function is called in every controller function to fetch that `userid` and then `userid` is set to view page.

I have to repeat that piece of code for every controller function, 
My query is that Is there a way to just a `userid` once in the controller and use that `userid` for every view.

my controller function :-

```
class asd extends Admin_Controller {
protected $role;   
public function _construct(){
    parent::_construct();
     $this->load->library('users/auth');
     $this->load->model('helpdesk_model');
     $role = $this->helpdesk_model->getRole($this->auth->username());
}
}
```

I am using `Template::set('role',$role);` in my controller function
my view :-

`<?php echo Template::get('role); ?>`

Its showing undefined variable role :(

My model :-

```
function getRole($username) {
        $this->db->select('role_id');
        $this->db->where('username',$username);
        return $this->db->get('tbl_users')->row();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a variable to the controller and initialize it in the constructor:

```
class Some_controller extends CI_Controller {
    protected $data;

public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->model('some_model');
       $this->data['user_id'] = $this->some_model->get_user_id();
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('my_view', $this->data);
    }
}
```

In the view you can access it like this:

```
echo $user_id;
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($role)` produce? Did you try accessing `$role` without `Template::get`?

Comment: You need to access the variable: $this->role. `$this->helpdesk_model->getRole($this->auth->username());` doesn't return a value.

Comment: in the model: `return $this->db->get('tbl_users')->row();` Where is the use of the `username` variable? You are retreiving the entire table and not a single record.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14529/discussion-between-yan-and-avinashse)

Comment: @Yan another problem arrises :(
How can I use assigned global variables in codeIgniter..
I am doing `private $a=10` and using  $a in my function but its showing undefined variable a

Comment: Do you mean class variables? If so, you need to access it $this->a not $a. If not, please open a new question regarding this matter.